# Connecting opscenter but no data

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I have deployed a datastax cassandra cluster on google cloud. The cluster size is 4 nodes on two different datacenters.

Servers are running fine and able to view opscenter but no data on it and getting the following errors.

This is a fresh deployment and all nodes are up and running. No tables were created yet.

**Error Message from opscenter log:**

```
[opscenterd] ERROR: Unhandled error in Deferred: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.UnavailableException: Not enough replicas available for query at consistency ONE (1 required but only 0 alive)
```

**address.yaml from one of the node:**

```
stomp_interface: 10.128.x.x [ ops center ip ]
agent_rpc_interface: 10.132.x.x [ one of the node ip]
agent_rpc_broadcast_address: 10.132.x.x

**cassandra.yaml from one of the node:**

cluster_name: 'Test Cluster'

num_tokens: 64



hinted_handoff_enabled: true
max_hint_window_in_ms: 10800000 # 3 hours

hinted_handoff_throttle_in_kb: 1024

max_hints_delivery_threads: 2

hints_directory: /var/lib/cassandra/hints

hints_flush_period_in_ms: 10000

max_hints_file_size_in_mb: 128


batchlog_replay_throttle_in_kb: 1024

authenticator: AllowAllAuthenticator

authorizer: AllowAllAuthorizer

role_manager: com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.auth.DseRoleManager

roles_validity_in_ms: 2000


permissions_validity_in_ms: 2000


partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner

data_file_directories:
     - /mnt/data

commitlog_directory: /mnt/commitlog

disk_failure_policy: stop

commit_failure_policy: stop

key_cache_size_in_mb:

key_cache_save_period: 14400

row_cache_size_in_mb: 0

row_cache_save_period: 0


counter_cache_size_in_mb:

counter_cache_save_period: 7200


saved_caches_directory: /mnt/saved_caches

commitlog_sync: periodic
commitlog_sync_period_in_ms: 10000

commitlog_segment_size_in_mb: 32


seed_provider:
    # Addresses of hosts that are deemed contact points. 
    # Cassandra nodes use this list of hosts to find each other and learn
    # the topology of the ring.  You must change this if you are running
    # multiple nodes!
    - class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider
      parameters:
          # seeds is actually a comma-delimited list of addresses.
          # Ex: "<ip1>,<ip2>,<ip3>"
          - **seeds: "XX.XXX.X.X" [ The node IP from different Data Center]**

concurrent_reads: 32
concurrent_writes: 32
concurrent_counter_writes: 32

concurrent_materialized_view_writes: 32

memtable_allocation_type: heap_buffers



index_summary_capacity_in_mb:

index_summary_resize_interval_in_minutes: 60

trickle_fsync: true
trickle_fsync_interval_in_kb: 10240

storage_port: 7000

ssl_storage_port: 7001

listen_address: **SAME NODE IP**

broadcast_address: **SAME NODE IP**



start_native_transport: true
native_transport_port: 9042



start_rpc: true

rpc_address: 0.0.0.0

rpc_port: 9160

broadcast_rpc_address: SAME NODE IP

rpc_keepalive: true

rpc_server_type: sync




thrift_framed_transport_size_in_mb: 15

incremental_backups: false

snapshot_before_compaction: false

auto_snapshot: true

tombstone_warn_threshold: 1000
tombstone_failure_threshold: 100000
```

**Opscenter.conf from opscenter:**

```
[webserver]

port = 8888

interface = 0.0.0.0

[authentication]

enabled = False

[stat_reporter]
```

**nodetool status**:

```
Datacenter: europe-west1-b

Status=Up/Down

|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving

-- Address Load Tokens Owns Host ID Rack

UN 10.XXX.0.2 220 KB 64 ? 5381a371-c532-4be7-a7f5-80162bef4541 europe-west1-b

UN 10.XXX.0.3 148.6 KB 64 ? e5b3dfec-f9bf-4952-b48f-b5a82749a9fe europe-west1-b

Datacenter: us-east1-b

Status=Up/Down

|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving

-- Address Load Tokens Owns Host ID Rack

UN 10.XXX.0.2 158.72 KB 64 ? b93980e0-3c28-4bb0-9e49-220cb009d44c us-east1-b

UN 10.XXX.0.3 192.85 KB 64 ? af242b71-b7b4-4345-9888-5b89eb5e6199 us-east1-b

Note: Non-system keyspaces don't have the same replication settings, effective ownership information is meaningless
```

Comment: Do you have multiple DCs? What version of OpsCenter? Can you include output of `nodetool status` ?

Comment: opscenter version is  6.0.2. Since nodetool status have longer output. I have posted the output in Answer section.

Comment: Can you provide your replication factor for the `OpsCenter` keyspace? (`cqlsh -e "describe keyspace \"OpsCenter\"" | grep KEYSPACE`)

Comment: CREATE KEYSPACE "OpsCenter" WITH replication = {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', '$dc': '2'}  AND durable_writes = true;

Comment: I see one of the log. [Test_Cluster] ERROR: The state of the following nodes could not be determined, most likely due to agents on those nodes not being properly connected:

Answer (score 1):

You have a DC in your replication factor ($dc) that doesnt exist, so when OpsCenter sends a request to read data the coordinator responds with an UnavailableException.

Try updating your keyspace like `ALTER KEYSPACE "OpsCenter" WITH replication = {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'us-east1-b': '2'}` and doing a full repair if you want to keep the data thats there.

If it hasnt run yet so you dont have data you want to save, just delete the opscenter keyspace (`drop keyspace "OpsCenter"`) and restart opscenterd and the agents (after opscenter service has started back up).